# Serverless signalr R doesnt invoke

Tags: angular, signalr, .net-6.0, serverless, signalr-client

i am trying to invoke a method on my azure function from a client with signalR serverless. I am establishing a connection that is successful, however when i try to invoke a method from the client it doesn't trigger the breakpoint on the server side. What should i do?

Serverside .NET

```
    public class PaymentHub : ServerlessHub{

     [FunctionName("negotiate")]
        public SignalRConnectionInfo Negociate([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous)] HttpRequest req)
        {
            return base.Negotiate(); //this always gets triggered
        }

     [FunctionName("identifyUser")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> IdentifyUser(
            [SignalRTrigger] InvocationContext invocationContext,
            string message
            )
        {
             var x = message; //this never gets triggered
             return new OkObjectResult(x); 
        }

 
    }
```

And on the client side i am using Angular. I have a signalRService.

in signal-r.service.ts

```
  public startConnection(){
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(this.connectionString);
      this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(this.connectionString).build();
      this.hubConnection.start()
        .then(() => {
          console.log("connection established");
          return resolve(true);
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log("error occured" + err);
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
public test(message:string){
    if(!this.hubConnection){
      console.log("hubConnection doest exist");
    }
    else{
      console.log(this.hubConnection);
      this.hubConnection.invoke('identifyUser',message).then(()=>{
        console.log('worked');
      }).catch((error)=>{
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
  }
```

and in main.component.ts

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
     this.signalRService.startConnection().then(()=>{
        console.log('connected');
         this.signalRService.test("my message is X"); 
        })
}
```

I always receive the message that the server was connected, alongside with a connectionId, but it seems like the hub doesn't trigger the method on the server side.

Comment: Did you configure your upstream on the Azure SignalR settings?